# How to add label or custom value on Mapchart's path using geoChoroplethChart and dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

[image]

```
var IndChart = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#india-chart");

var states = data.dimension(function (d) {
            return d["state_name"];
        });

var stateRaisedSum = states.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
            return d["popolation"];
        });

     IndChart
                        .width(700)
                        .height(500)
                        .dimension(states)
                        .group(stateRaisedSum)
                        .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain().range(["#27AE60", "#F1C40F", "#F39C12","#CB4335"]))
                        .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) { //console.log(d.properties.name);
                            return d.id;
                        })
                        .projection(d3.geo.mercator().center([95, 22]).scale(940))
                        .renderLabel(true)
                         .title(function (d) { console.log(d); return d.key + " : " + d.value ;
                        })
                        .label(function (d) { console.log(d);}) ;
```

wanted to add Label or custom value(25%, added in Map chart screen-shots) in map chart for each path using dc.js.

Comment: There's nothing built-in, so I think you would need to use the `pretransition` event, compute the centroid of the regions (although in your example they don't all seem to be centered on regions?) and then draw the labels using D3. It's usually pretty easy to add any missing functionality to dc.js, it was originally intended as more of a cookbook than a library.

Comment: Thanks.
Already i tried with 'pretransition' and 'renderlet'. Labels are coming but not at position on Path. Transform methods passing correct value but Label are showing in sequence outside of Map chart. Can you share me any working link or script.

Comment: I checked dc.js library script. There are not added any methods for geoChoroplethChart's label like other charts(B ar, pie, line etc).

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to say - no one has implemented this feature in the library yet. Sounds like you're on the right track - if you edit your question and add a fiddle or other reproducible example of what you've tried, I will be glad to help you debug it. (It's generally frowned on to ask for examples on SO - instead share what you've done and ask for help.)

Comment: Link- http://jsfiddle.net/9VJHe/118/ This is the one working example on jsfiddle. But, i want to add Label for multiple Map charts in one page. What i have to do here for 2nd Map chart, how can i pass the separate chart id to select separate chart's svg? var labelG = d3.select("svg") .append("svg:g") .attr("id", "labelG") .attr("class", "Title");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments above, you found or created a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9VJHe/118/) that answers your original question. Then you asked how to make it work for two charts on the same page.

This is just a matter of getting the selectors right, and also understanding how dc.js renders and redraws work.

First off, that example does

```
var labelG = d3.select("svg")
```

which will always select the first `svg` element on the page. You could fix this by making the selector more specific, i.e. `#us-chart svg` and `#us-chart2 svg`, but I prefer to use the [chart.select()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#select__anchor) function, which selects within the DOM tree of the specific chart.

Next, it's important to remember that when you render a chart, it will remove everything and start from scratch. This example calls `dc.renderAll()` twice, so any modifications made to the first chart will be lost on the second render.

In contrast, a redraw happens when any filter is changed, and it incrementally changes the chart, keeping the previous content.

I prefer to listen to [dc.js chart events](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor) and make my modifications then. That way, every time the chart is rendered or redrawn, modifications can be made.

In particular, I try to use the `pretransition` event whenever possible for modifying charts. This happens right after drawing, so you have a chance to change things without any glitches or pauses.

Always add event listeners before rendering the chart.

Adding (the same) handler for both charts and then rendering, looks like this:

```
    usChart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        var project = d3.geo.albersUsa();

        var labelG = chart.select("svg")
            .selectAll('g.Title')
              .data([0])
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("id", "labelG")
            .attr("class", "Title");

        labelG.selectAll("text")
            .data(labels.features)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .text(function(d){return d.properties.name;})
            .attr("x", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];})
            .attr("y", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];})
            .attr("dx", "-1em");
    });

    usChart2.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        var project = d3.geo.albersUsa();

        var labelG = chart.select("svg")
            .selectAll('g.Title')
              .data([0])
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("id", "labelG")
            .attr("class", "Title");

        labelG.selectAll("text")
            .data(labels.features)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .text(function(d){return d.properties.name;})
            .attr("x", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];})
            .attr("y", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];})
            .attr("dx", "-1em");
    });
    dc.renderAll();
```

I used one more trick there: since `pretransition` happens for both renders and redraws, but we only want to add these labels once, I use this pattern:

```
        .selectAll('g.Title')
          .data([0])
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "Title");
```

This is the simplest [data binding](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) there is: it says we want one `g.Title` and its data is just the value `0`. Since we give the `g` element the `Title` class, this ensures that we'll add this element just once.

Finally, the result of this expression is an enter selection, so we will only add `text` elements when the `Title` layer is new.

[Fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/az7Lb8g0/23/).

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Yes Gordan. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers when they help you (by clicking the green check mark). It spreads a few "fake internet points" and it also helps those of us who follow tags, to know where to focus our effort. Thanks!